Sefer of Talmudic Laws that were omitted by the Rambam and Shulchan Aruch
Not to be confused with the following question, which deals with the obligation to follow laws that are mentioned in the Talmud but are not mentioned in the [Rambam and] Shulchan Aruch.
If a law is in the talmud, and not in the shulchan aruch, then is it followed, or not followed?
I seem to remember that there is a sefer that goes through Shas, and notes all the laws that were omitted by the Rambam and/or the Shulchan Aruch, and discusses why the codifiers didn't mention these laws.
Does anyone know the name of such a sefer?

ספר שכחת האומר (pretty sure that's the name but don't see it showing up on google)

Hmm maybe I had it backwards https://hebrewbooks.org/35657

@DoubleAA See the answer that I posted.

I originally thought that the sefer אומר השכחה, by Rabbi Yeshaya Pick/Berlin deals with this topic. However closer examination of the sefer shows that it merely seeks to correct the omissions which were due to external censorship, and doesn't deal with the laws that were omitted by the Rambam and/or the Shulchan Aruch.
However, there is another "אומר השכחה" from the same author, which is found at the end of his sefer "קשות מיושב", starting here, which deals with these omissions.
I also found the following Hebrew article on the SEFORIM BLOG,by Ezra Brand:
תורת הצורה והחומר וההעדר: ספרים המדברים בהשמטות הרמב”ם ובכללים להסבירם

Note the pun עומר השכחה the forgotten sheaf
